# ESP8266 ESP-01 drive 6V led with GPIO with 2AA batteries as source

Tags: arduino, led, esp8266

I have an ESP-01 with two AA Batteries directly connected as power source.

I have a button and led wired up to the GPIO. With a standard led it is bright enough when I add new batteries, but after time the led lights very low.

Now I want to connect a button with integrated 6 V led to GPIO. How can I drive the 6 V led with 3.3 V GPIO?

The ESP-01 is in idle in deep-sleep and if I press the button the reset is performed and after the ESP has done it's work it goes to sleep again.

Comment: Does the LED light up when you connect it directly to the batteries? If not, you need to get 6V somehow, first.

Comment: Where are LED specs?

Comment: The specs are 6V 15mA. The requirement is to use this 2AA Batteries as power supply. Is there a circuit i can build with a little Inductance to step up the voltage from GPIO?

Comment: `button with integrated 6 V led` any way to replace the LED? ... can you post a link to the button web page?

Comment: Here is the link to the button:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/GQ16F-10E-J-16mm-LED-light-ring-lamp-type-metal-push-button-switch-with-Flat-round/32275583964.html?spm=a2g0s.8937420.0.0.6e1e2e0exRcTzW

I inspected the button but i don't find any option to replace the led.

Comment: You're not going to get 3.3v output on your GPIO if you're powering your MCU off 2xAA batteries (assuming alkaline batteries).  Your batteries will only produce 3.1v when fully charged, and the GPIO output of the ESP8266 is only 80% of Vcc, so at best 2.5v. But it gets worse: [within a few hours of usage, your battery voltage will drop below 3v](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/aa-alkaline-discharge-curve-5ma), which is the minimum Vcc specified for your MCU.  Independent tests suggest it can actually operate a little lower (maybe 2.7v), but that can't be guaranteed.

Comment: But, even assuming the best case, you're only only going to be able to use 15-20% of your battery capacity before the circuit fails.  I'd suggest upping your supply voltage to 6v and using a buck regulator to power the MCU board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a low current boost converter, something like [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs776b/slvs776b.pdf)

Comment: Of course, depending on your size requirements, using a pre-assembled module may well save you both time and (in fact) money.  You can get boost modules from Chinese suppliers for [remarkably little money](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-DC-SX1308-Step-UP-Adjustable-Power-Module-Step-Up-Boost-Converter-2-24V-to-2/32807568140.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use a voltage booster to achieve 6v first. Then use an optocoupler like PC817 or mosfet like BS170 to drive a 6V logic component from ESP, due to the voltage level difference.

Comment: BS170's a good suggestion.  A 2N7000 *may* work in this application (due to low current), but I wouldn't want to guarantee it.  Generally, they're not great on 3.3v circuits, but I see them recommended all over the place, which is often confusing.